# How can I find all work items in a given board column via Azure DevOps API?

Tags: rest, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I’m building an application that fetches information from our Azure DevOps board. One of the tasks is to get all tickets present in a given column.

I’ve spent quite a lot of time reading through their docs but all the methods rely on you passing the IDS you want to get back, while what I’m looking for is for the API to tell me what work items do exist in a given column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to find the work items in a board column would be to use the [Wiql - Query by Wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) API.  The usage will look very similar to how you just use the UI query functionality to find work items.

Given some work items in this kind of board state (using Basic template):

[image]

Example in PowerShell below:

```
$AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($AzureDevOpsPAT)")) }

$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=6.0"

$body = @{
  "query" = "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From WorkItems Where [System.BoardColumn] = 'Doing'"
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $uri -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader -Body $body -ContentType 'application/json' |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty workItems
```

Returns:

```
id url                                                                                     
-- ---                                                                                     
26 https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workItems/26
```

Comment: System.BoardColumn is not necessarily the column name, is it? Maybe its state?

Comment: You mentioned board column in your question.  It can be disjoint from the state.  You can also just query on state if that is what you really want.

Comment: I was searching for quick solution to get a list of workitems from Boards API. This is a great example, just needed to adjust the query a bit, run it in Postman and voila, thanks! So, in my case the query written directly in Json to get not closed User Stories from specific Area Path looks like this: {
  "query": "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'User Story' and [System.AreaPath] = 'your_area' and [System.State] <> 'Closed'" 
}